# Как в JavaScript нужно правильно деинициализировать объект?

Tags: javascript

Достаточно ли в JavaScript для того, чтобы деинициализировать объект, установить `this` в `null`? Под деинициализировать я имею в виду полностью удалить его, очистив занимаемую им память.

Например, можно ли внутри метода совершенно другого класса сделать так:

```
class MainClass() {
    constructor() {
        this.anotherClassObject = new AnotherClass();
    }
    destroyAnotherClassObject() {
        this.anotherClassObject = null;
    }
}

mainObject = new MainClass();
mainObject.destroyAnotherClassObject();
```

Достаточно ли будет этого, чтобы удалить объект и, главное, освободить из-под него память?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `javascript` объект полностью удалится только в том случаи, если до него будет невозможно добраться из объекта `window`. То есть пока до объекта можно добраться по ссылкам начиная от самого корневого объекта `window`, то он будет находится в памяти, `Garbage Collection` или сокращенно `GC` его не уничтожит.

Другими словами, чтобы объект был удален, нужно удалить на него все ссылки.

Конкретно в Вашем случаи достаточно просто "занулить" ссылку на сам экземпляр.

```
class SomeClass {

}

let someInstance = new SomeClass();

someInstance = null; // этого достаточно чтобы объект был удален из памяти
```

Если рассматривать конкретный пример автора (код ниже), то вышесказанное верно и для него. Ведь ссылка `someInstance` на экземпляр класса `SomeClass` объявлена в глобальном контексте и уже по ней можно получить доступ к созданному внутри экземпляру другого класса `AnotherClass` - `window.someInstance.anotherInstance`.

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor(){
    this.anotherInstance = new AnotherClass();
  }

  destroy(){
    this.anotherInstance = null;
  }
}

let someInstance = new SomeClass();

// если по какой-то причине экземпляр someInstance
// остается нужным, а необходимости в экземпляре AnotherClass
// уже нет, его можно удалить вызвав someInstance.destroy()
```

И напоследок остается напомнить что в `js` с помощью замыканий можно имитировать приватный свойства и функции, до которых будет невозможно добраться от самого корневого объекта, что вызовет увеличение потребления памяти до тех пор, пока не будет удален объект содержащий в себе это замыкание.

Comment: То есть я правильно сделал?

Comment: Прошу прощения, сразу не заметил что у Вас в примере уничтожается класс внутри другого класса. Если Вы хотите не удалять объект класса `MainClass`, использовать его в пуле, то Вы все верно сделали. Если же Вам он не нужен, то нулить объект `AnotherClass` не обязательно, достаточно удалить сам  `MainClass`.

Comment: А если сам `MainClass` мне еще нужен, а объект, являющийся инстансом `AnotherClass` - нет, то достаточно занулить, как сделал я? Верно?

Comment: Да, достаточно. Вы правильно сделали.

Comment: А, все, я понял к чему вы. Вы про что-то типа "наследственного удаления", или зависимостей при удалении.

Comment: Тогда все ясно. Спасибо.

Comment: Кстати, было бы неплохо, если бы вы добавили это в ответ. Мало ли пригодится кому.

Answer (score 0):

Объект в JavaScript будет удален когда на него никто не будет ссылаться. Если Ваш объект занимает много памяти (например содержит в себе большой массив данных) и Вам нужно принудительно ее освободить, то напишите какой-нибудь метод Free у класса, который эту память освободит и вызывайте его по необходимости.

Но опять таки, эта память освободится, когда на нее никто не будет ссылаться. Так, что целесообразно такие поля делать приватными

Comment: "Напишите <...> который эту память освободит" - *как*?

Comment: Конечно же сбросив на нее ссылку `this.BigMemory = null`