# Удаление всех ссылок на объект для полной его деинициализации

Tags: javascript

При переписывании ранее написанного кода понадобилось держать в памяти все экземпляры класса. Все экземпляры класса хранятся как статическое свойство (строка *) (если можно его так назвать) в виде массива, который пополняется новым элементом при создании нового экземпляра класса. Код имеет следующий вид:

```
class Child {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    (Child.__instances__ = Child.__instances__ || []).push(this); // *
  }
}

class Doughter extends Child {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
}

class Son extends Child {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
}

class DifferentClass {
  constructor() {

  }

  initializeChildren() {
    this.son       = new Son("Ваня");
    this.doughters = [new Doughter("Маня"), new Doughter("Аня")];
  }

  removeVanya() {
    console.log("Ваня помирает");
    this.son = null;
  }
}

let obj = new DifferentClass();
obj.initializeChildren();
obj.removeVanya();
console.log(Child.__instances__);
```

Если выполнить этот код, то можно увидеть, что, даже не смотря на то, что в объекте `obj` свойства `son` больше нет, то все равно данный экземпляр остался в массиве `__instances__`. А, [как известно из уже данных ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586479/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82), экземпляр класса существует ровно до тех пор, пока на него хотя бы откуда-то ссылаются.

Я решил пойти по пути наименьшего сопротивления и напрямую удалить нужный (точнее ненужный больше) элемент, что, по понятным причинам, успехом не увенчалось:

```
removeVanya() {
  console.log("Ваня помирает");
  Child.__instances__[this.son] = null;
  this.son = null;
}
```

Собственно, вопрос в том и состоит: **как удалить нужный элемент в массиве `__instances__`, чтобы больше нигде не содержалось этого экземпляра?**

Comment: Я с классами работаю довольно тривиально, и таких задач не появлялось, но почему нельзя использовать оператор delete?

Comment: @DimenSi, `delete` убивает индекс в массиве и в нем остается дырка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

поле `__instances__` - является массивом. Для удаления элемента из массива можно применить метод [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Для этого нужно знать индекс удаляемого элемента. Определить индекс можно с помощью метода [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

В итоге функция удаления может принять вид:

```
removeVanya() {
  console.log("Ваня помирает");
  var childIndex = Child.__instances__.indexOf(this.son);
  if(childIndex != -1)
    Child.__instances__.splice(childIndex,1);

  this.son = null;
}
```

В текущем же коде, при вызове `Child.__instances__[this]=null` идет преобразование `this` в строку, скорее всего `[Object object]`, и присваиванию в одноименное свойство в массиве значения `null`.

Comment: А где можно прочитать, что такое `__instances__` ?

Comment: @DimenSi это массив, хранящий в себе все экземпляры данного класса, в коде вопроса `*` отмечен.

Comment: Вроде бы как ваш код не работает. Чтоб не ошибиться, копировал и вставил ваш код. Либо я что-то упускаю, либо он действительно не работает.

Comment: А, ну правильно. Должно быть `indexOf(this.son)`, а не просто `indexOf(this)`. И да, у меня в коде тоже должно было быть `Child.__instances__[this.son]=null`. И тогда поведение именно такое, как вы и сказали.

Comment: @smellyshovel, да, почему-то не обратил внимания что должно было быть `this.son`. Поправил

Comment: @Grundy все равно спасибо большое. Именно про `indexOf()` мне и необходимо было узнать.